# Will HTTP/2 in Azure App Service auto fallback to HTTP/1.1 for legacy browsers

Tags: azure-web-app-service, http2

I want to turn on HTTP/2 for my web app hosted by Azure App Service. However, 1% of my users are using browsers that doesn't support HTTP/2.

**Does Azure App Service automatically fallback to HTTP/1.1 for these browsers even if I've turned HTTP/2 on?**

In other words,

**When turn on HTTP/2 in Azure app service instance, will the server accept HTTP/1.1 request from browsers?**

I checked the Azure App Service announcement [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-http-2-support-in-azure-app-service/), but it doesn't say if auto-fallback is support or not.

Comment: Hey. I have myself searched for confirmation on http/1.1 fallback if http/2 is enabled. Can you point me to the conversation you had with the Azure team, or some docs that clearly says it?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment 6 months after... there isn't any article/document when I contact the Azure team. I know someone there, hence it's an offline conversation.

Comment: but does it fallback?

Comment: From our observation, it does fallback.

Comment: Worrying lack of official info that it falls back, I'm changing my website and this post is all I have to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the article [HTTP/2 support in Azure Front Door Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http2): yes, it will.

I know the article is about Azure Front Door Service, but if that enables old browsers to fallback, App Service will do so too. And of course, App Service supports both 1.1 and 2.0.

> **HTTP/2 browser support**
>   All of the major browsers have implemented HTTP/2 support in their current versions. Non-supported browsers automatically fallback to HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Thanks, @rickvdbosch. I also contact with Azure app service, they confirmed the server will accept HTTP/1.1 request from browsers if HTTP/2 config is on.