# Can enabling HTTP/2 on an AppService cause problems?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

It is quite easy do [enable HTTP/2 on Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/announcing-http-2-support-in-azure-app-service/). However, it is still disabled for existing components and also for new ones. Why is that?

Unsecured requests are still served by HTTP 1.1 if I enable the feature. Can enabling HTTP/2 have any negative impact for my site? Our apps run on .NET, ranging from .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET 5.0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabled `HTTP 2.0` in your webapp, you need clear cookies and sessions, then you will find your webapp is works fine with `HTTP/2` . Or wait a little longer.

*1. You can open a new inprivate  window, it works for me.*

*2. The second question is that enabling HTTP 2.0 will not have a negative impact on your application.*

**Related Posts：**

[① Will HTTP/2 in Azure App Service auto fallback to HTTP/1.1 for legacy browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836115/will-http-2-in-azure-app-service-auto-fallback-to-http-1-1-for-legacy-browsers/55836414#55836414)

*3. The third point, there are also considerations about the correct version of .Net Framework, 4.6.2 and above all support HTTP 2.0.*

## The above results are given through the test.

**I have tested that HTTP Version is supported in `.NET Framework 4.6.2` and above. So your first question, you can open the privacy window and try again.**

Comment: Thank you. So do you have an idea why it is not enabled by default if there are seemingly no downsides?

Comment: @AlexAIT According to the links of my other documents, I see that HTTP 2.0 requires webserver support, so I think it’s not impossible to create http 2.0 applications directly. When a client request enters the server, there should be a verification process that needs to verify whether it supports 2.0.

Comment: @AlexAIT Because the HTTP protocol or technology is being updated and iterated, I think the Microsoft product group should consider compatibility with all web applications, so HTTP 1.1 is set by default. Maybe not all web applications currently support 2.0.